# How it is possible that the Spark storage tab shows "size in memory" usage that far exceeds the memory available?

Tags: apache-spark

I must be misunderstanding something about the spark Storage tab shown at http://localhost:4040/storage/.
My laptop has about 12G allocated to spark and only 32G total, but the storage tab shows that over 400G of data is cached in memory, and nothing has spilled to disk. I am caching tables using

```
sqlContext.sparkSession.catalog.cacheTable(key, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
```

Is this a bug or a misunderstanding? I think it must be a bug because when I click on the largest cached table (150G) and look at the details, it says that the on Heap Memory Usage is 155.1GB (-512861675879.0 B Remaining).

Things worked as I expected on Friday when I was using it. I could see that it stored no more than about 2.1G in memory and the rest was getting stored on disk when needed. But when I cam in Monday morning, the storage tab looked as the image below shows. I also include my envirmonment info below. I'm using spark 2.3.0.

[image]
[image]